# Confidence intervals from bootMer in R, and pros/cons of different interval types

Tags: r, mixed-model, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, bootstrap

I've created a mixed effects model using `lme4` in R:

```
model <- lmer(GrowthRate ~ I(Year-1970) * factor(PlotType) + (1 + I(Year-1970)|Plot), data = dat)
```

- Or a working example for SE:

  ```
  model <- lmer(uptake ~ conc * factor(Type) + (1 + conc|Plant), data = CO2)
  ```

Next, I use `predict` to determine the trend:

```
pred <- predict(model,re.form = NA)
```

I want to **calculate 95% confidence intervals around my trend line(s)**, but `predict.merMod` does not calculate standard errors. The authors suggest using `bootMer`:

> There is no option for computing standard errors of predictions because it is difficult to define an efficient method that incorporates uncertainty in the variance parameters; we recommend `bootMer` for this task.

So I use `bootMer`:

```
boot <- bootMer(model, predict, nsim = 10000, re.form = NA)
```

**This is where I'm stuck**.

**How do I extract standard errors from `bootMer`? (and how do I convert these to CIs?)**

### Attempts:

I. [This source](http://www.remkoduursma.com/post/2017-06-15-bootpredictlme4/) suggests to do the following for a single predicted value:

```
b <- bootMer(fm1, nsim=100, function(x) predict(x, newdata = data.frame(Year = 1990), re.form=NA))
```

> *(paraphrasing):* `b$t` lists the output of the function we applied to each of the bootstrap resamples, in this case the fitted values at the given predicted value of `x`. 
>   The standard error of our predicted value can be estimated simply as the standard deviation of the sampling distribution: `sd(b$t)`
>   and the confidence interval as the quantiles of the distribution (in this case, a 95% confidence interval):
>   `quantile(b$t, probs=c(0.025, 0.975))`

However, does this approach "scale up" to calculate the CIs for the entire trend line(s)?

- It doesn't appear to, since `sd(boot$t)` only gives a single value  as it did with `b$t` in the above example.

II. [This source](https://www.r-bloggers.com/confidence-intervals-for-prediction-in-glmms/) uses an entirely different approach:

```
#Bootstrapped CIs:     [modified slightly for this question]

#Create model matrix:
    mm <- model.matrix(~ I(Year - 1970) * factor(PlotType),dat)

#define a function to be applied to the nsim simulations:
  #(the function basically gets a merMod object and returns the fitted values)
  predFun <- function(.) mm%*%fixef(.) 

#supply function to bootMer:
  bb <- bootMer(m, FUN = predFun, nsim = 200) #do this 200 times

#as we did this 200 times the 95% CI will be bordered by the 5th and 195th value   <<--- #WHAT DOES THIS MEAN??
  bb_se <- apply(bb$t,2,function(x) x[order(x)])
  blo <- bb_se[1,]
  bhi <- bb_se[2,]
```

I don't understand 2 things from this approach:

1. Why they created `predFun()`, and whether that is more valid than simply using `predict(re.form = NA)`
2. How their `apply` approach (and failure to multiple SEs by 1.96) *actually* get them 95% confidence intervals...

III. When I look at the output of `bootMer` (i.e., by entering my saved object `boot` in my console using `print(boot)`), I get the following output with `length(pred)` number of rows:

```
Call:
bootMer(x = model, FUN = predict, nsim = 10000, re.form = NA)


Bootstrap Statistics :
       original       bias    std. error
t1*    8.235689 -0.239843268   1.0835271
t2*    8.154482 -0.232643708   1.0579350
t3*    8.046205 -0.223044295   1.0265019
.....
```

So it appears `bootMer` is already calculating standard errors (`std.error`). However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to access these values.

- I assume this would be the easiest approach if anyone knows how to do so...

  - **Update:** So I found out I can reproduce the `std.error` values from `print(boot)` using the following: `apply(boot$t, 2, sd)`. However, now this calls into question whether the `boot` output is showing standard errors or simply standard deviations...

### Final Question(s):

1. Can anyone explain the above methods and their pros and shortcomings?
2. Which of these above methods is most appropriate?
3. Is there an alternative approach I should instead use?

---

#### Update:

Here is my final attempt/approach (having not yet received a response to my Q):

```
  #load packages:
    library(lme4)
    library(ggplot2)

  #Build model:
    model <- lmer(uptake ~ conc * factor(Type) + (1 + conc|Plant), data = CO2)

  #Predict values:
    pred <- predict(model,re.form = NA)

  #Bootstrap CI:
    boot <- bootMer(model, predict, nsim = 100, re.form = NA)
    std.err <- apply(boot$t, 2, sd)
    CI.lo <- pred - std.err*1.96
    CI.hi <- pred + std.err*1.96

  #Plot
   ggplot(CO2, aes(x = conc, y = uptake, colour = Type)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = pred),size=2) +
    geom_line(aes(x = conc,y = uptake,group = Plant), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = CI.lo, ymax = CI.hi),size=2, alpha = 0.03, linetype = 0)
```

Other than being a really bad model fit, **does this approach seem legitimate and sound?**

Comment: really, I'll also take answers that definitively and clearly show how to calculate bootstrapped 95% CI bands around my LMM model trend line...

Comment: Well here's a familiar face... :) I think the question I marked as duplicate is close to the best answer you'll get. The big question is really "which confidence intervals are you really talking about?" because there are many non-equivalent ways to approach the problem. The merTools vignette https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html was quite helpful to me, whether or not you actually end up using merTools.

Comment: As far as how to compute confidence intervals...merTools can do it for you simply, but in the bootstrapping realm you are talking about *empirical confidence intervals* - they aren't going backwards to compute a standard error because they aren't assuming the distribution of the error must be normal. They are literally getting a list of possible outputs, and saying that the 97.5th percentile of those possibilities is an upper and 2.5th percentile is a lower bound for an overall 95% confidence interval.

Comment: Well hey, @Bryan! Hmm definitely a related post, but it doesn't quite answer _how to use bootMer_. I've gotten so far with this approach, I'd at least like to know how to finish the job before trying an alternative approach ;)

Comment: Let me know if my second comment helps with that.

Comment: Also, the merTools vignette I linked also has a comparison with bootMer including all the necessary code - I'd start there if what I said didn't make sense.

Comment: hmm certainly makes sense theoretically, yeah. I have to think how to apply that to bootMer...aaand based on your last comment, I 'll start by examining the vignette. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76913/discussion-between-bryan-krause-and-theforestecologist).

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question title to make it more clear to casual observers that this is not just a question about how to do something in R (if it were, it would be [off-topic here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found two very near similar approaches for calculating 95% confidence intervals. (*Similar in that they produce almost the same CIs*).

Both start with running the `bootMer()` function:

```
    merBoot <- bootMer(model, predict, nsim = 100, re.form = NA)
```

The approaches are:

1. Using a quantile approach *ala* [Knowles & Frederick (2016)](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html):

   ```
   CI.lower = apply(merBoot$t, 2, function(x) as.numeric(quantile(x, probs=.025, na.rm=TRUE)))
   CI.upper = apply(merBoot$t, 2, function(x) as.numeric(quantile(x, probs=.975, na.rm=TRUE)))
   ```
2. Pulling standard errors from `bootMer` object and converting to CIs via `CI = mean +/- 1.96*SE`:

   ```
   std.err <- apply(merBoot$t, 2, sd)
   CI.lower <- pred - std.err*1.96
   CI.upper <- pred + std.err*1.96
   ```

Note: these might just be similar in my case because the test data I used might have been normal enough. I don't believe the first approach requires normalcy, while the standard error approach relies on such an assumption.

Comment: This is old now, but I would really appreciate your thoughts on the following. Firstly, doesn't the first approach give prediction intervals, rather than confidence intervals? The authors in the linked vignette call the output a 95% prediction interval. Secondly, did you ever find out why `bootMer`'s `std.error` is equal to the output of `apply(boot$t, 2, sd)`?

Comment: I've answered the first part of my Q: the answer here uses `re.form = NA` in `predict`, which results in predictions that do not take random effects into account. As a result, `quantile` returns a CI. In contrast, in the reference `re.form = NULL` is used. This results in predictions that account for random effects and a prediction interval from `quantile`. See [here](https://theoreticalecology.github.io/AdvancedRegressionModels/2C-RandomEffects.html#predictions) and [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_randomeffects.html).